# What plus means in method declaration in perl6?

Tags: raku

What does plus mean in method declarations in Perl6?

Here is an example from [spec](http://www.perl6.org/archive/doc/design/apo/A12.html)

```
submethod BUILD (+$tail, +@legs, *%extraargs) {
    $.tail = $tail;
    @:legs = @legs; 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**2019 Update** See the section **Variadic positionals destructuring; `+@foo` and `*@foo`** in [my answer to the SO question "variable number of arguments to function/subroutine"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713872/1077672).

---

In 2015 Larry Wall introduced the [`+` parameter prefix](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Slurpy_conventions), one of four parameter prefixes (`*`, `**`, `+`, `|`) that signify [slurpy (variadic) parameters](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Slurpy_(A.K.A._variadic)_parameters). He added it to the Rakudo compiler, added some tests, gave [a brief informal description of it on the irc channel](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2015-09-17#l664), and added [a section on it](http://design.raku.org/S06.html#One-argument_slurpy_binding) to the relevant language design doc.

---

The example quoted in the original question is taken from an archive of an informal document written and frozen in time over a decade ago. At that time a `+` parameter prefix signified [a named parameter as contrasted with a positional one](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Positional_vs._named_arguments). Nowadays we use `:` for that, thus:

```
submethod BUILD (:$tail, :@legs, *%extraargs) {
    $.tail = $tail;
    @.legs = @legs;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your "spec" links goes to a historical document, and the syntax has long gone from Perl 6. I'm not sure what it used to do, maybe "at least one argument", in analogy to the `+` quantifier in regexes.

For an up-to-date specification, please read http://perlcabal.org/syn/S06.html which contains all the information on signatures and subroutines.