# Variable number of arguments to function/subroutine

Tags: raku

I want to be able to run a function with a variable number of parameters in Raku, but after reading through https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Arguments I don't see how it can be done.

I want to do something like this:

```
some-test($v1, $v2)
```

or

```
some-test($v3)
```

but not have a separate function using `multi` for each

How can I construct a *Raku* subroutine which will accept a variable number of strings?

Comment: So $v3 is a different value to $v1?

Comment: @Scimon all the variables given to the function/subroutine should be independent, so yes, $v3 should be different from $v1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR** You're asking about variadic functions.<sup>1</sup> Simple use is simple. Some Raku features, most notably positional and named arguments, and variadic destructuring, add some wrinkles. Also, see the other answers which are very helpful too.

> variable number of arguments

Simple use of a simple variadic function:

```
sub variadic (|args) { say args .elems }
variadic();           # 0
variadic('1');        # 1
variadic('1', '2');   # 2
```

A `|foo` parameter slurps up all remaining arguments into a [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture) bound to sigilless identifier `foo`:

```
sub variadic ($a, @b, %c, |others) { say others[0] }
variadic 1, [2,3], (:foo), 4, [5,6], (:bar); # 4
```

In the above example the `others` parameter "slurps"<sup>1</sup> up the last three listed arguments starting with the `4`.

## Variadic variations

Things aren't always simple:

```
variadic(1, 2);       # 2 -- works but args are Ints
variadic(:foo,:bar);  # 0 -- where did :foo, :bar go?
variadic((:foo));     # 1 -- works; arg is Pair (:foo)
variadic((1, 2));     # 1 -- works; arg is List (1,2)
```

In the rest of this answer I explain:

- Constraining arguments, eg ensuring they're all strings.
- *Positional* vs *named* arguments; `**@foo` and `*%foo`
- Variadic positionals destructuring; `+@foo` and `*@foo`

## Constraining arguments

> variable number of **strings**

You can impose any constraints you want on slurped arguments by using a [`where`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-where_clause) clause. (Which you can in turn package into a [`subset`](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-subset-subset) if you want.)

For example, to constrain all the arguments to be of type `Str`:

```
sub variadic (|args where .all ~~ Str) { say args .elems }
variadic();         # 0
variadic('1');      # 1
variadic('1', '2'); # 2
variadic(1);        # Constraint type check failed
```

## *Positional* vs *named* arguments; `**@foo` and `*%foo`

Raku supports both [*positional* and *named* arguments](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Positional_vs._named_arguments).

Using `|foo` in a signature always captures all remaining arguments, both positional and named:

```
sub slurps-into-WHAT (|args) { say WHAT args }
slurps-into-WHAT(); # (Capture)
```

A [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture) stores positional arguments in an internal list accessible via positional subscripting (i.e. `args[...]`) and named arguments in a hash accessible via associative subscripting (i.e. `args<...>` or `args{...}`):

```
sub variadic (|args) { say " {args[1]} {args<named2>}" }
variadic('pos0', 'pos1', named1 => 42, named2 => 99); # pos1 99
```

Sometimes it's preferable to collect just named args, or just positional ones, or to collect both but in separate parameters.

To collect named args, use a parameter of the form `*%foo` (one asterisk prefix and a hash arg):

```
sub variadic-for-nameds (*%nameds) { say %nameds }
variadic-for-nameds(:foo, :bar); # {bar => True, foo => True}
```

(Note that *all* methods collect named args in this way even if their signature doesn't explicitly say so.<sup>2</sup>)

To collect positional args, use a parameter of the form `**@foo` (two asterisk prefix immediately followed by an array arg):

```
sub variadic-for-positionals (**@positionals) { say @positionals }
variadic-for-positionals(1, 2, 3); # [1 2 3]
```

## Variadic positionals destructuring; `+@foo` and `*@foo`

Raku provides a range of non-variadic [argument destructuring features](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-destructuring_arguments).

The first variadic positionals destructuring parameter form is `+@foo`. This has exactly the same effect as `**@foo` except in one case; if the variadic parameter gets just a single argument, and that argument is a list or array, then the parameter is bound to the content of that list or array, stripping away the list/array container:

```
sub variadic-plus (+@positionals) { say @positionals }
variadic-plus(1,2,3);   # says same as for **@positionals
variadic-plus(1);       # says same as for **@positionals
variadic-plus([1]);     # [1]     -- instead of [[1]]
variadic-plus((1,2,3)); # [1 2 3] -- instead of [(1 2 3)]
```

The `+@foo` form was introduced to support the ["single arg rule"](https://docs.raku.org/language/list.html#Single_Argument_Rule). It's used by core devs writing built ins. Users may wish to use it when they want the same behavior.

The other variadic positionals destructuring form is `*@foo`. It does the same thing as `+@foo` in that it extracts the content from list or array container args and throws the container away. But it's much more aggressive:

- It does this for all arguments.
- If an argument is a list rather than an array (`(...)` rather than `[...]`) then it descends into that list and recursively repeats the exercise if an element of the list is itself another inner list or array.

Thus:

```
sub variadic-star (*@positionals) { say @positionals }
variadic-star((1,2),[3,4]);             # [1 2 3 4]
variadic-star((1,2),(3,4,(5,6,(7,8)))); # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
variadic-star((1,2),(3,4,[5,6,(7,8)])); # [1 2 3 4 5 6 (7 8)]
```

(Note how it stripped the container from the `[5,6,(7,8)]` array but did not descend into it.)

One final thing; are there variadic named destructuring parameters? You tell me.<sup>3</sup>

## Bonus section: `foo(...)` vs `foo  (...)`

(I included this bonus section in the hope it heads off confusion. If this section is itself confusing, just ignore it.)

Routine calls can be written with or without parentheses around their list of arguments and they mean the same thing. The opening parenthesis  must follow the routine name immediately, without intervening whitespace:

```
sub foo  (|args)  { say args[0] }
foo 'a', 'b';    # a
foo('a', 'b');   # a
```

(This rule only applies to the routine **call**, between the routine name and its **arguments**. It does not apply to the routine **declaration**, between the routine name and its **parameters**. For the latter, the declaration, you can leave no space or use space as I have above with `sub foo  (|args)` and it makes no difference.)

If you insert whitespace between the `foo` and the opening parenthesis in a call you're writing something different:

```
foo  ('a', 'b'); # (a b)
```

That calls `foo` with **one** argument, the one list `('a', 'b')` in contrast to `foo('a', 'b')` which calls `foo` with **two** arguments, the two values inside the parentheses.

The following calls `foo` with **two** arguments, both of which are lists:

```
foo ('a', 'b', 'c'),  ('d', 'e', 'f'); # (a b c)
```

You may nest parentheses:

```
foo(  ('a', 'b', 'c'),  ('d', 'e', 'f')  )    ; # (a b c)
foo  (('a', 'b', 'c'),  ('d', 'e', 'f'))      ; # ((a b c) (d e f))
foo( (('a', 'b', 'c'),  ('d', 'e', 'f')) )    ; # ((a b c) (d e f))
```

The latter two `foo` calls get **one** argument, the one list `( ('a', 'b', 'c'),  ('d', 'e', 'f') )` (that happens to contain two inner lists).

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> The standard industry term for this is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). At the time of writing this answer, the Rakudo Raku compiler uses the industry standard term ("variadic") in error messages but the official Raku doc tends to use the word "slurpy" instead of "variadic" and talks of "slurping up arguments".

<sup>2</sup> Methods always have an implicit variadic named parameter called `%_` if one is not explicitly specified:

```
say .signature given my method foo {} # (Mu: *%_)
```

<sup>3</sup> The Raku language and/or the Rakudo Raku compiler currently allows parameters to be written in the form `+%foo` and `**%foo`. It doesn't really make sense to have variadic nameds destructuring. Perhaps that explains why both these forms do insane things:

- `**%foo` appears to be indistinguishable from `%foo`.
- `+%foo` appears to be indistinguishable from `**@foo` except for using the identifier `%foo` instead of `@foo`. The object bound to `%foo` is an `Array`!

Comment: what is the purpose of the `**` and `+@`? These don't appear to exponentiate and add

Comment: thanks for writing all of that, I'll get to reading it soon.  I really appreciate all of the work that you put in to that answer!

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to be able to take 1 or 2 values then the easiest way is to mark the second value as optional :

```
sub some-test( $v1, $v2? ) { ... }
```

Or you can define a default value :

```
sub some-test( $v1, $v2="default" ) { ... }
```

Or if you want any number of values (1 or more) you can use a slurpy with a where clause :

```
sub some-test( *@v where *.elems > 0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: this fails with `Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '@v'; expected anonymous constraint to be met but got Array ($["a", "b"])` :-(

Comment: Can you share the subroutine definition you used? $["a","b"] should match the where clause of *.elems > 0 (as it's got 2 elements).

Comment: `sub some-test (*@v where *.elems < 0) {
 for @v -> $v {
  put $v
 }
}
my $x = 'a';
my $y = 'b';
some-test($x, $y);
`

Comment: So you are testing elems < 0 which is true arrays with negative elements in. Instead of you test for elems > 0 then you won't accept an empty array but will accept others

Comment: Another option to get at least one value is to use `sub some-test($v1, *@rest) { }`

Answer (score 8):

You can use signature [destructuring](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Destructuring_arguments)

```
sub some-test(*@all [$first, *@rest]) { ... } # must have 1 or more parameters
```