# Using a Capture like a Slurpy

Tags: capture, raku

I've been reading about [Captures](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture) and this paragraph intrigued me:

> Inside a Signature, a Capture may be created by prefixing a sigilless
>   parameter with a vertical bar |. This packs the remainder of the
>   argument list into that parameter.

This sounds a lot like a `**@` (non flattening) slurpy, so this concocted this test code:

```
my $limit=1_000_000;
my @a=1 xx 10000;
my @b=-1 xx 10000;

sub test1(|c){
    1;
};

sub test2(**@c){
    1;
};
{ 
    for ^$limit {
        test1(@b,@a);
    }
    say now - ENTER now;
}
{
    for ^$limit {
        test2(@b,@a);
    }
    say now - ENTER now;
}
```

A sample run gives durations of each test block:

```
0.82560328                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2.6650674
```

The Capture certainly seems to have the performance advantage. Is there a down side to using a `Capture` as a slurpy in this fashion? Have I over simplified the comparison?

Comment: When using subroutines the capture `|c` will take 'Unexpected named argument(s)' that a non-flattening slurpy `**@c` won't.

Comment: See also [my answer to SO **variable number of arguments to function/subroutine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713872/1077672).

Comment: I guess the real question is what are you going to do with c?

Comment: @CurtTilmes no direct plans, just to learning about Captures  and looking for simple performance gains for calling subs repeatedly a large number of times

Comment: I don't know that there is a particular down side -- if it works in your situation, use it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Capture` has two slots, holding a VM-level array (positional arguments) and hash (named arguments). It is quite cheaply constructed, and - since `|c` style arguments are quite common in various bits of the internals - has been well optimized. Since a capture parameter slurps up both positional and named arguments, any named arguments will be silently ignored. That's probably not much of an issue for methods, where unrequired named arguments will be silently placed into `%_` anyway, but might be a consideration if using this construct on a `sub`, since it's not a pure optimization: it changes behavior.

The `**@c` case allocates an `Array`, and then allocates a `Scalar` container for each of the passed values, placing them into the `Scalar` containers and those `Scalar` containers into the `Array`. That's a reasonable amount of extra work.

There's another case not considered here, which is this one:

```
sub test3(**@c is raw){
    1;
}
```

That places a `List` in `@c`, and sets its elements to refer directly to the things that were passed. This is a bit cheaper than the case without `is raw`. In theory, it could probably perform as well as - if not better than - a capture parameter like `|c`; it probably just needs somebody working on the compiler to have a dig into why it doesn't yet.

In summary, if not caring about enforcing itemization and/or having a mutable `Array` of incoming arguments, then adding `is raw` is probably a better optimization bet than picking a capture parameter: the argument processing semantics are closer, it's already a bit faster, will allow for more natural code, and has future potential to be every bit as fast as, if not faster, than `|c`.

Comment: A quick test with ` |c`, `+@c`, `**@c` and `**@c is raw` give durations of `0.8427187, 2.593368, 2.8757735 and 2.8949438`. It probably depends on the use case but the `Capture` seems the quickest in this simple test.